# expected value properties

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I'm reading an algorithm proof in which there is a passage I can't understand.
Substantially we have 2 statistically independent random arrays $X$ and $Z$, and a third random array $Y$.
It's known that $Y=XZ$ and $E[Z] = 1$. What the author provides are textually the following passages:
\begin{align}
VAR[Y] &= E[(Y -E[Y])^2]\\
&= E[(X(Z-1) + (X-E[X]))^2]\\
&= (VAR[X]+E[X^2])VAR[Z]+VAR[X]
\end{align}
where $E[X]$ and $VAR[X]$ are the expected value (i.e. mean) and the variance of $X$, respectively.

Trying to understand that proof, I'm getting a different result, as it is:
\begin{align}
VAR[Y] &= E[(Y -E[Y])^2]\\
&= E[(XZ - E[XZ])^2]\\
&= E[(XZ -X +X -E[X])^2]\\
&= E[(X(Z-1) + (X-E[X]))^2]\\
&= E[X^2(Z-1)^2 + (X - E[X])^2 + 2X(Z-1)(X - E[X])]\\
&= E[X^2]E[(Z-1)^2] + VAR[X] + 2E[X(Z-1)(X - E[X])]\quad \text{(then, as $E[Z] = 1$)}\\
&= E[X^2]VAR[Z] + VAR[X] + 2E[X^2Z - ZXE[X] - X^2 + XE[X]]\\
&= E[X^2]VAR[Z] + VAR[X] + 2E[X^2Z] - 2E[ZXE[X]] - 2E[X^2] + 2E[XE[X]]]\\
&= E[X^2]VAR[Z] + VAR[X] + 2E[X^2]E[Z] - 2E[XE[X]]E[Z] - 2E[X^2] + 2E[XE[X]]]\\
&= E[X^2]VAR[Z] + VAR[X] + 2E[X^2] - 2E[XE[X]] - 2E[X^2] + 2E[XE[X]]]\\
&= E[X^2]VAR[Z] + VAR[X] \neq (VAR[X]+E[X^2])VAR[Z]+VAR[X]
\end{align}

Can you help me to understand where am I wrong?
Thank you very much in advance for your attention.

EDIT:
This is the original author proof
[image: algorithm proof]

Comment: There is a misprint in your reproduction of the author's final formula, where $E(X^2)$ should read $E(X)^2$. Then the author's formula and yours become equivalent (and both correct).

Comment: Ok, I added the original author proof passage (5.3).
Can you give me a more detailed explaination of the formulae equivalence?
thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears that the misprint is yours and that the author wrote a correct formula: you wrote $E(X^2)$ for $\bar x^2=E(X)^2$. // The equivalence between the result of your computations and what is (really) written in the book is clear since $\mathrm{Var}(X)+E(X)^2=E(X^2)$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. Why do you say mine is a misprint? if you follow the passages it should really be $E[X^2]$ and not $E[X]^2$, or have I done something wrong in my calculations?
thank you again for your attention.

Comment: @Alfatau: What do you mean by "it should really be"? As Didier rightly points out, it *does* say $\bar x^2$ and not $\overline{x^2}$, and it also *should* say that, so there's neither a descriptive nor a normative discrepancy; all there is is that you copied it incorrectly and thereby introduced an error.

Comment: AH! Now I think I finally understood! I'm sorry, maybe I need some pause. The problem was the author notation led me to a wrong interpretation of the formula.
Really thank you to all.

Comment: @Alfatau: I don't see any problem with the author's notation. It seems to me that you led yourself to a wrong interpretation of the formula.

Comment: Removed tag (proof-theory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see in what sense $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are arrays, especially given $E[Z]=1$; I'll assume that they're just random variables. (Also where you write "pass" it seems you mean "passage".)

Your calculation is correct. You can check this using a simple example, for instance $X$ and $Z$ both uniformly drawn from $\{0,2\}$.

You could considerably shorten your calculation by noting that the expected value of any term of the form $f(X)(Z-1)$ vanishes; that gets rid of the mixed term that the last few lines focus on.

Comment: Yes. And see my comment.

Comment: ok, thanks.
$X$,$Y$,$Z$ are random arrays and not random variables because they represent sampled sequences of data and each element of $Z$ has an exponential distribution with the same mean and standard deviation. In the proof it has been initially supposed $E[Z] = 1$.
however, I still don't understand why my result is different from the author's one.
Any idea about it?

Comment: @Alfatau: What you write about arrays and variables appears to indicate a confusion on your part. The *mean* of the values in a random array can be $1$, but the *expectation* of a random array is an array. You can have an array of samples drawn from a random variable, but that doesn't turn the random variable into an array, and it doesn't change the fact that $Z$ and $E[Z]$ necessarily have the same dimensions, so if $E[Z]$ is a number, then $Z$ is a random variable.